# Self hosted Bitbucket persmission

Tags: bitbucket-server

So,

I am evaluating Bitbucket from Atlassian on a self hosted server and I've got this problem, if I don't give access to a repo the logged user can't see the repo, but
he can clone it using smartgit for example if he knows the link; probably I am doing something wrong but for my needs this is a security problem.

Any idea why this is happening?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This definitely shouldn't happen, and I'm sure there's a good explanation. Your best would be to contact our support team at support.atlassian.com and we can help you out.